# countdown timer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

trying to do a countdown timer in C# on micrsoft visual studio 
minimum value of 10seconds, maximum of 2hours
need a display when timer runs out
how do i implement this?
thanks

Comment: winform?webform?wpf?silverlight?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) wherein you can specify how much time should pass until the timer fires, and what code to execute when the timer does fire.

You can also look at the [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).

For a comparison of all the timer-like classes in .NET, check out [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use timers from `System.Timer`  or `System.Threading .Timer` depends upon your needs. and execute your code in each interval.

have a look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

if its a simple winforms app like u mentioned its a countdown app consider `Forms.Timer` its easier to implement. Just drag and drop the control from toolbox and perform countdown in `Tick` Event. 
have a look for it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx