# Difference between .net timers

Tags: .net, windows

There are several **Timers** under .NET.

Is someone can explain clear what's the main difference
 between them and when we have to use it? (Including `DispatcherTimer`)

Thanks!!

Comment: This type of question has been discussed multiple times on SO already.  For example, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706152/countdown-timer